# Listview with copy-paste

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, copy-paste

Is there an easy way of adding copy-paste for a listview, or should I just switch to DataGridView instead?

My application is kinda like an address book, it contains emails, numbers etc where copy paste would be useful.

Answer (score 21):

The example below handles the Ctrl-C as a copy to the clipboard command, and copies the second column's value from all the selected rows:

```
    private void resultsListView_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender != resultsListView) return;

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
            CopySelectedValuesToClipboard();
    }

    private void CopySelectedValuesToClipboard()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in resultsListView.SelectedItems)
            builder.AppendLine(item.SubItems[1].Text);

        Clipboard.SetText(builder.ToString());
    }
```

Use `item.Text` for the first column, and `item.SubItems[n].Text` for other columns.

References:

1. [What is the KeyChar for Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5824457e-9112-43ef-83df-7037a36dd365/what-is-the-keychar-for-ctrlc-and-ctrlv-in-c) to get the keys and proper event handler.
2. [Copy ListView to Clipboard in VB.NET, C#, and VB6](http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2007/06/copy-listview-to-clipboard.html) for full example of copying ListView to the Clipboard.

Comment: Good solution, I just had to do that with the `KeyDown` event. `KeyUp` did not work, because when pressing the `c` it was auto-selecting the first entry in the ListBox which started with a `c`, rendering my multiselection to just a single one.

Comment: I was getting an invalid expection on `builder.AppendLine(item.SubItems[1].Text);` Instead, I had to use `builder.AppendLine(item.Text);`

Answer (score 1):

It's not very difficult to do manual copy and paste, just put in an event handler for `KeyDown` (or maybe it's `KeyPress` can't remember but fairly sure it's one of them) and check what key is pressed by looking at `e.KeyCode` and check if `e.Control` is true. If it's one of `x`, `c` or `v` just call `Clipboard.SetText` or `Clipboard.GetText` to write/read to/from the clipboard.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) for the MSDN documentation of the `Clipboard` class.

You could add a context menu with Copy and Paste on to the ListView also to make it complete.

Comment: The problem with that is I only manage to copy the entire row, unless there is some neat tricks for selecting a cell.

Comment: @Zubirg: Yes, I forgot that you don't really have cells in a `ListView`, it might be easier to switch to a `DataGridView`. However, if you do want to stick with the `ListView` you could do something like handling `Click` and `MouseDown` events on it to calculate what subitem was clicked and then changing the `BackColor` of that subitem to make it look selected and then you could handle copy and paste for just that subitem.
You'd have to make sure to set `UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;` on the Item though, otherwise the colours won't show on the subitems.

Answer (score 1):

I've made it as method (depending on @brett's top answer), so just execute once on Form initialization:  `copyableListView(myListView)` and it will do itself.

Code:

```
private void copyableListView(ListView listView)
{
    listView.KeyDown += (object sender, KeyEventArgs e) =>
    {
        if (!(sender is ListView)) return;

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in (sender as ListView).SelectedItems)
                builder.AppendLine(item.Text + Environment.NewLine);
            Clipboard.SetText(builder.ToString());
        }
    };
}
```

Also, on form destroy, you should have method to remove all subscribed-events, i.e.

```
void myDeinit()
{
    myListView=null;
    myListView2=null;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My requirement was to add a button to copy a list of serial numbers to the clipboard.  I added the button in the normal fashion and then added the following method:

```
private void btnClipboard_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String clipText = string.Empty;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in lstSerials.Items)
    {
        clipText += item.SubItems[0].Text;
        clipText += Environment.NewLine;
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(clipText))
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(clipText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did I get down-voted?  This implementation works!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Brett's answer, I wrote this method that copies the whole selected rows instead of just a single column (Especially good when FullRowSelect = true).

Two more improvements:

1.Ignore any newline - as ListView does.

2.Avoid an exception when no row is selected - Just clear the clipboard.

```
private void ListViewLogs_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    CopySelectedRowsToClipboard(listViewLogs, e);
}

private void CopySelectedRowsToClipboard(ListView listView, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.SelectedItems)
        {
            var subItems = item.SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem>()
                .Select(subItem => subItem.Text);
            builder.AppendLine(string.Join(", ", subItems).Replace(Environment.NewLine, ""));
        }

        if (builder.Length > 0)
            Clipboard.SetText(builder.ToString());
        else
            Clipboard.Clear();
    }
}
```